How can I do arithmetic in the ORDER BY clause with a column aliased in my SELECT clause?
The following is illegal.
SELECT
  schema_id + 2 AS evil_column
FROM
  sys.tables
ORDER BY
  evil_column + 3;

If you remove the + 3, then it is legal.
Assuming that I want to do arithmetic with evil_column and ORDER BY the result but do not want to repeat the definition of evil_column anywhere, what are my options?

Do you have a less trivial example for your goal? Are you trying to do math with an additional column rather than a constant value? Applying constant algebraic transformations (add/subtract/multiply/divide by a constant value) would be no different from ordering by evil_column (or even schema_id) here.

You can use a number of CROSS APPLY which feed into each other to add "virtual" columns.
SELECT
  v1.evil_column
FROM
  sys.tables t
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT t.schema_id + 2 AS evil_column
) v1
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT v.evil_column1 + 3 AS evil_column2
) v2
ORDER BY
  v2.evil_column2;


No not directly
but you can always use a CTE as Step
WITH 
CTE As (SELECT
  schema_id + 2 AS evil_column
FROM
  sys.tables)
  SELECT evil_column FROM CTE 
ORDER BY
 (evil_column+3)
 ;

